# symbology changes colour when harvested from WMS to online map

Tags: wms, symbology

I'm harvesting a web map service and from my legend the symbology is pink but the same feature on the online map is green?
I've had a look at the GetCapabilities file and opened the legend png and it's pink. Does anyone have an idea as to why the colour is changing once visualised on my map?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1)` I believe that you use `PNG8 (8-bit PNG)` or `GIF` as **Default Cache Format** for your layer tiles.

Remember that PNG8 can handle up to 256 colors, similar to GIF. Therefore, you see pink instead of your expected color.

Try to use `PNG (24-bit PNG)` or `JPEG` instead.

Or,

`2)` you have a `format` parameter in your WMS request, set to `PNG8/GIF/TIFF8/GeoTIFF8`.

Check, please [`WMS output formats`](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/outputformats.html)